# Why does my cross-validation consistently perform better than train-test split?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, train-test-split

I have the code below (using sklearn) that first uses the training set for cross-validation, and for a final check, uses the test set. However, the cross-validation consistently performs better, as shown below. Am I over-fitting on the training data? If so, which hyper parameter(s) would be best to tune to avoid this?

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)
#Cross validation
rfc = RandomForestClassifier()
cv = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=5)   
scoring = {'accuracy', 'precision', 'recall', 'f1', 'roc_auc' }
scores = cross_validate(rfc, X_train, y_train, scoring=scoring, cv=cv)
print(mean(scores['test_accuracy']),
      mean(scores['test_precision']),
      mean(scores['test_recall']),
      mean(scores['test_f1']),
      mean(scores['test_roc_auc'])
      )
```

Which gives me:

```
0.8536558341101569 0.8641939667622551 0.8392201023654705 0.8514895113569482 0.9264002192260914
```

Re-train the model now with the entire training+validation set, and test it with never-seen-before test-set
    
    RFC = RandomForestClassifier()
    
    RFC.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = RFC.predict(X_test)
    
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
    precision = precision_score(y_test, y_pred)
    recall = recall_score(y_test, y_pred)
    f1 = f1_score(y_test, y_pred)
    y_pred_proba = RFC.predict_proba(X_test)[::,1] 
    auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred_proba)
    
    print(accuracy,
          precision,
          recall,
          f1,
          auc
          )

Now it gives me the numbers below, which are clearly worse:

```
0.7809788654060067 0.5113236034222446 0.5044687189672294 0.5078730317420644 0.7589037004728368
```

Comment: you might want to use regularization

Comment: Hi, I think it is not right to compare the result, because, the cross-validation score is the best score calculate in `training dataset`, while the second model's score is calculate on the `testing dataset`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to reproduce your scenario with [Pima Indians Diabetes Dataset](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/pima-indians-diabetes.csv).

The difference you see in the prediction metrics is not consistence and in some runs you may even notice the opposite, because it depends on the selection of the X_test during the split - some of the cases will be easier to predict and will give better metrics and vice versa. While Cross-validation runs predictions on the whole set you have in rotation and aggregates this effect, the single X_test set will suffer from effects of random splits.

In order to have better visibility on what is happening here, I have modified your experiment and split in two steps:

### 1. Cross-validation step:

I use the whole of the X and y sets and run rest of the code as it is

```
rfc = RandomForestClassifier()
cv = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=5)
# cv = KFold(n_splits=10)
scoring = {'accuracy', 'precision', 'recall', 'f1', 'roc_auc'}
scores = cross_validate(rfc, X, y, scoring=scoring, cv=cv)
print(mean(scores['test_accuracy']),
      mean(scores['test_precision']),
      mean(scores['test_recall']),
      mean(scores['test_f1']),
      mean(scores['test_roc_auc'])
      )
```

Output:

```
0.768257006151743 0.6943032069967433 0.593436328663432 0.6357667086829574 0.8221242747913622
```

### 2. Classic train-test step:

Next I run the plain train-test step, but I do it 50 times with the different train_test splits, and average the metrics (similar to Cross-validation step).

```
accuracies = []
precisions = []
recalls = []
f1s = []
aucs = []

for i in range(50):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)
    RFC = RandomForestClassifier()

    RFC.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = RFC.predict(X_test)

    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
    precision = precision_score(y_test, y_pred)
    recall = recall_score(y_test, y_pred)
    f1 = f1_score(y_test, y_pred)
    y_pred_proba = RFC.predict_proba(X_test)[::, 1]
    auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred_proba)
    accuracies.append(accuracy)
    precisions.append(precision)
    recalls.append(recall)
    f1s.append(f1)
    aucs.append(auc)

print(mean(accuracies),
      mean(precisions),
      mean(recalls),
      mean(f1s),
      mean(aucs)
      )
```

Output:

```
0.7606926406926405 0.7001931059992001 0.5778712922956755 0.6306501622080503 0.8207846633339568
```

As expected the prediction metrics are similar. However, the Cross-validation runs much faster and uses each data point of the whole data set for testing (in rotation) by a given number of times.

Comment: Thanks, you're right: CV and repeated train-test have the same result, with CV being the right approach in this case because of the reasons you mentioned. The mistake I was making was that I was balancing my training data (code not shown), and using that balanced training data for CV, and of course the balanced data in CV were producing better results that the original imbalanced dataset used for train-test split.